# Meaning of $ \sup_{n}f_{n}(x)$

Tags: measure-theory, notation

What does $ \sup_{n}f_{n}(x)$ mean? In what sense is one function "bigger" than the other?

Context: If $\{f_{n}\}_1^{\infty}$ is a sequence of measurable functions, then  $ \sup_{n}f_{n}(x)$ is a measurable function.

Comment: This is also called the pointwise supremum of the sequence $f_n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each $x$, the function $\sup_n f_n$ maps it to the value $\sup \{f_n(x):n=1,2,3,\dots\}$.

For example, if $f_1(x)=0$ for $x<0$, $f_1(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$, $f_2(x)=1$ for $x<0$, $f_2(x)=0$ for $x\geq 0$, then $\sup_{n=1,2} f_n(x)=1$ for $x\in\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

It means $\sup\limits_n f_n(x) = \sup\limits_n\{f_n(x)\}$. That is, for each fixed $x$, you take the supremum of $\{f_n(x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.